# Determining the Stationary Distribution of a Homogeneous Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I am trying to solve the following:

Let $P$ be a matrix of transition probabilities of a homogeneous ergodic
Markov chain on a finite state space such that $p_{ij} = p_{ji}$. Find its stationary distribution.

I know from the Ergodic Theorem for Markov Chains that since the Markov chain is ergodic there exists a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ and the n-step transition probabilities converge to the distribution $\pi$ that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ij}^{n}=\pi_{j}.$

How do I actually apply the Ergodic Theorem for Markov chains to compute the stationary distribution in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $p_{ij} = p_{ji}$ for all $i,j$,  we may state that $p_{ij}^n = p_{ji}^n$ for any $n$ (and any $i,j$).  It therefore follows that for all $i,j$, we have
$$
\pi_i = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ji} = \lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ij} = \pi_j
$$
conclude that $\pi$ is the uniform distribution.

Comment: There are other ways to prove the statement, but this method uses the Ergodic theorem.